# Why my Geometry filter in SQL Server is not working?

Tags: sql-server, gis, geospatial, spatial, geometry-surface

I have uploaded the Local Government Area Boundary of the NSW, Australia into my MS-SQL database and try to filter for Sydney Area.

Following is the my Script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[nsw_lga_polygon_shp](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [geom] [geometry] NULL,
    [lg_ply_pid] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [dt_create] [date] NULL,
    [dt_retire] [date] NULL,
    [lga_pid] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [nsw_lga_sh] [date] NULL,
    [nsw_lga__1] [date] NULL,
    [nsw_lga__2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [nsw_lga__3] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [nsw_lga__4] [date] NULL,
    [nsw_lga__5] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_nsw_lga_polygon_shp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
END
```

GO

```
    select 
    Geom.STGeometryType() as ShapeType,
    geom.STBoundary().ToString() as Boundary,
    Geom,
    nsw_lga__2 
from 
    [nsw_lga_polygon_shp]
where
nsw_lga__2 like '%SYDNEY%'
```

Result:

ShapeType "MultiPolygon"
[image]

However, I don't know why when I try to use the filter function, It does return me anything.

Following is my script

```
select 
        Geom,
        nsw_lga__2
    from 
        [nsw_lga_polygon_shp]
    where
        Geom.Filter(geometry::Parse('POLYGON((  150 -33, 152 -33 , 152 -34 , 150 -34 , 150 -33 ))')) = 1
```

I as expecting to see the two LGA from my first query and also all surrounding LGAs. Could anyone share a light on how to fix my problem?

Thanks in advance!

---

As requested, I have added the result using EnvelopeAggregate:

[image]

I now notice it is the due to different SRID.

Comment: What happens if you plot all three shapes (i.e. your two council shapes and your box) in SSMS? Also curious what `STEnvelope` of your multipolygon returns as.

Comment: I am not using STEnvelope, but using filter to filter the shape.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. What I'm asking for will help me to troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi Ben, Very helpful, I now noticed the problem is due to different SRID. However, I don't know how to get my SRID because I actually download the shape file from the internet and then used QGIS to upload into SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one common issue *could be* the Native `SRID` was not set and needs to be specified in Database Utilities feature class properties, or not set.

Run this to find out:

```
 -- Please replace MYTABLE with your `Table`
 select distinct SP_GEOMETRY.STSrid from dbo.MYTABLE
```

Now, if the SRID is not available in the drop-down, but one can simply type your `SRID` for e.g. `3395` into the Native SRID field.

After specifying the Native SRID correctly, SQL Server spatial filters work as designed.

---

Also you can re-project your data using these [SpatialTools](https://github.com/Microsoft/SQLServerSpatialTools)

Ref: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stsrid-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hi Transformer, I tried your script:

"select distinct SP_GEOMETRY.STSrid from dbo.[nsw_lga_polygon_shp]"

But what I got is 

"Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "SP_GEOMETRY.STSrid" could not be bound."

Comment: Hi Transformer,  I find it by using  "select distinct
 Geom.STSrid SRID
from 
 [nsw_lga_polygon_shp]"

Comment: @ELeung I am glad it work for you :) , I should have added a comment that replace the `MyTABLE` name with your table `nsw_lga_polygon_shp`. sorry, I was busy with some other work.

Comment: that's OK. you and Ben guide me through, Thanks for all of yours help!

Answer (score 0):

After assisting from Ben and Transformer, I work out the problem and find the solution.

Following is my final script:

```
select distinct
    Geom.STSrid SRID
from 
    [nsw_lga_polygon_shp]
```

Result: 4283

```
declare @J as Geometry;

set @j = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((  150 -33, 152 -33 , 152 -34 , 150 -34 , 150 -33 ))',4283);

select 

    Geom,
    nsw_lga__2
from 
    [nsw_lga_polygon_shp]
where
    --NSW_LGA__2 like '%SYDNEY%'
    Geom.Filter(@j) = 1
```

Thanks for everyone's help!